# problem with SQL query in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, timestamp

How can i write a query in DB2 for following thing:

The difference between current timestamp and a timestamp field in dB should be >=4 hours AND
<= 24 hours

Answer (score 2):

You don't really give enough information to answer the question (i.e., do you want data only from the past, only in the future, etc), but let's assume you want the data where the timestamp column ("tscolumn") is more than 4 hours old and less than 24 hours old:

```
select * 
from   table t
where  t.tscolumn between current timestamp - 4 hours 
                      and current timestamp - 24 hours
```

If my assumption is wrong it's pretty easy to rewrite this to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
select * from tableName where 
                 date <=  DATEADD(Hour, -4, CURRENT_TIME) and 
                 date date >=  DATEADD(Hour, -24, CURRENT_TIME)
```

Comment: thanks for replying.But i dint get it.Can u provide some brief describtion

Comment: DATEADD is not a standard function available in DB2.

Answer (score -2):

```
select * 
from   table t
where  timestampdiff(8,char(current timestamp - time_from_table)) between 4 and 24
```

here timestamp(8, - refers hours, below are the values for different arguments.

Value   Description

```
1   Fractions of a second
2   Seconds
4   Minutes
8   Hours
16  Days
32  Weeks
64  Months
128 Quarters
256 Years
```

Comment: -1: You're converting timestamps to char, which is completely unnecessary (and may break the subtraction).  `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` also only returns an _estimate_, and doesn't take things like DST into account (days are always considered to be 24 hours long) - although DB2 may not have great support for that anyways, depending on the version.  The use of the multiple functions will completely ignore any indices.  Your last sentence is completely opaque.  The formatting of your answer is poor.... and you answered a question more than 3 years old, with acceptable answers (so why?).

Comment: follow below link and check the syntax for timestampdiff http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_bif_timestampdiff.htm

Comment: You have to convert the _result_ of the subtraction to char, **not** the operands; I seriously doubt that you can subtract strings from each other... Oh, and the statement has a syntax error regardless.  I'd avoid your answer in general simply because it won't take advantage of any indices, and `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` only providing an estimate (that gets more inaccurate the bigger the difference is).  The OP didn't really specify enough information, but there _might_ be improvements available for existing answers; however, at 3 years old, with no accepted answer....